# recuperar nome do BD de uma conexão mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Bom faço a conexão no meu mysql assim:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '123', 'teste');
```

Quero saber como posso recuperar o nome do banco de dados através da variável que recebe a conexão '$mysqli'.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Execute um SQL `select database()` para retornar o nome do database MySQL, por exemplo:

```
mysql> select database();
+--------------------+
| database()         |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: OK, mas quero retornar o nome do BD da conexão que esta na variável '$mysqli'. Tentei assim: '$mysqli->query("select database()");' mas não deu certo

Answer (score -1):

Bom a solução foi essa aqui:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql, $login_bd_mysql, $senha_bd_mysql, "CIDADES");


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
printf($row[0]);
```